# Como acessar dados enviados por PUT (ajax) no php?

Tags: php, ajax, http-request, requisição

Estou criando uma aplicação em formato REST na qual meu front-end solicita um PUT (Pelo ajax) ao back-end.
No request estou enviando as novas informações para update, porém não estou conseguindo acessar estas informações no PHP,
Dei uma pesquisada sobre o assunto, sei que o PHP não tem definido a super global $_PUT como a $_POST.
Me deparei com pessoas buscando os dados do `php://input` mas quando realizo o procedimento `parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $teste);` o retorno não vem em Array. Alguém já passou por isso e pode me dar uma luz?
Obs.: Não estou utilizando frameworks para o back-end.

**Código PHP**
Tenho um arquivo de rotas que chama o método.

```
    public static function update($param){
        parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $teste);
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($teste);
        exit;

    }
```

**Código JavaScript**

Método para realização de chamadas PUT

```
function putAjax(uri, data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (callback) {
            for (var i = 0; i < callback.length; i++) {
                callback[i](data);
            }
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        fechaLoading();
        return false;
    });
}
```

Método que está chamando o putAjax

```
function updateServidores(form) {

    var verificaRetorno = function (data) {
        if (data.status) {
            if (data.status === true) {
                servidor.splice(indiceUpdateServidores, 1);
                servidor.push(data.data[0]);
                montaGrid(".tableServidores");
                abreTela("#viewServidores");

                notify("success", "Sucesso!", "Item alterado com sucesso!");

            }else {
                notify("error", "Erro!", data.erro.message);
            }

            indiceUpdateServidores = null;
        }
    };

    after = [];
    after.push(verificaRetorno);

    var formData = new FormData(form);
    putAjax(url + "servidor/" + servidor[indiceUpdateServidores].ID_SERVIDORES, formData, after);
}
```

Saída do `file_get_contents('php://input')`:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarynQKeRELA6A6uJMkr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nome"

deletaServidor(this);
------WebKitFormBoundarynQKeRELA6A6uJMkr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="servidor"

deletaServidor(this);
------WebKitFormBoundarynQKeRELA6A6uJMkr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="porta"

deletaServidor(this);
------WebKitFormBoundarynQKeRELA6A6uJMkr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

deletaServidor(this);
------WebKitFormBoundarynQKeRELA6A6uJMkr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="senha"

deletaServidor(this);
------WebKitFormBoundarynQKeRELA6A6uJMkr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email_envio"

deletaServidor(this);
------WebKitFormBoundarynQKeRELA6A6uJMkr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="reply"

deletaServidor(this);
------WebKitFormBoundarynQKeRELA6A6uJMkr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="alias"

deletaServidor(this);
------WebKitFormBoundarynQKeRELA6A6uJMkr--
```

Comment: posta o código ai para saber o que vc já fez

Comment: @WeesSmith Adicionei o código no texto.

Comment: @LucasJunior da uma olhada no link que o LuizFelipe falou ai

Comment: @LuizFelipe e @WeesSmith Testei a solução descrita sem sucesso. Estou a receber um array com uma única string com todos os dados do `php://input`

Comment: A pergunta fala de obter dados do PUT, mas na verdade a dúvida é sobre como fazer o parse do form (e nos comentários da resposta que fala em JSON foi comentado que a solução foi trocar o formato dos dados, não refletindo mais o problema exposto). Desta forma, não vejo como a pergunta e resposta possam servir para outros visitantes, por isto foi fechada.

Answer (score 2):

Se você está recebendo os dados no backend no formato JSON, deve usar a função `json_decode` e não `parse_str`:

```
public static function update($param){
    $teste = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($teste);
    exit;
}
```

Dessa forma a variável `$teste` conterá um objeto ou array dependendo do que foi enviado

Você pode usar `$teste = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` para que os objetos sejam transformados em arrays associativos

Comment: ao fazer isso recebo no retorno NULL.

Comment: O `var_dump` mostra `null`? Então qual a saida de `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));`? Adicione na pergunta

Comment: Adicionei a saida do var_dump como solicitado..

Comment: Na chamada ajax adicione a configuração `contentType: 'application/json'`. Deve resolver

Comment: Com seu comentário me antentei a outra coisa.
Meu `data` estava sendo gerado por um `FormData` realizei a conversão dos dados para formato json a adicionei o `contentType: 'application/json'`. Problema resolvido.

Comment: Exatamente, se não for informado um formato, é enviado daquele jeito. Você pode usar outros formatos e decodificar a entrada de forma apropriada